# PXE Boot Proxmox

Tags: linux, boot, pxe

I followed [this](https://www.ostechnix.com/how-to-install-pxe-server-on-ubuntu-16-04/) guide to set up a PXE server on an ubuntu VM.  Instead of the DHCP server on that same server though, I just configured OPNSense to use that server.

I made the boot image using [this](https://github.com/morph027/pve-iso-2-pxe) script and put the `initrd.img` and `linux26` file in `/var/www/boot/proxmox`.

I have an apache webserver with the root at `/var/www`.  The tftp server is set to root `/var/lib/tftpboot`.  I copied the `proxmox` directory (containing `initrd.img` and `linux26`) into both `/var/www` and `/var/lib/tftpboot`.

I have OPNSense to use `pxelinux.cfg/default` as the default bios filename (located in `/var/lib/tftpboot/pxelinux.cfg/default`).

But when I try to use another VM to boot using the server, it gets to the point where it gets a DHCP lease, shows me the network info, then doesn't do anything.

[image: VM failed to boot]

Contents of `pxelinux.cfg/default`: (I confirmed that the files listed here are accessible).

```
UI http://10.0.5.0/boot/menu.c32
PROMPT 0
DEFAULT Proxmox


MENU TITLE ..:: My PXE Menu ::..
MENU CLEAR


LABEL Proxmox
    MENU LABEL Proxmox
    LINUX http://10.0.5.0/boot/proxmox/linux26
    APPEND vga=791 video=vesafb:ywrap,mtrr ramdisk_size=16777216
    INITRD http://10.0.5.0/boot/proxmox/initrd.iso.img splash=verbose

LABEL Proxmox2
    MENU LABEL Proxmox2
    LINUX proxmox/linux26
    APPEND vga=791 video=vesafb:ywrap,mtrr ramdisk_size=16777216
    INITRD proxmox/initrd.iso.img splash=verbose
```

How can I get past this point?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the Label Proxmox one - PXE can't load over http the kernel but proxmox2 should in theory boot okay

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the DHCP server isn't sending the 'next-server' info.  Normally the Intel PXE BIOS would print something about TFTP loading the boot kernel, and you'd see the requests in your TFTP log.

I'd double-check your OPNSense config to make sure it has the IP info for your TFTP server.